# need to create a stored procedure but having issues

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am not sure why the below code is giving errors when I try to create a stored procedure. I am relatively inexperienced with SP.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDuplicateFields] 
    (@UniqueColID varchar(50), @IndividualID varchar(50) = null)
AS
Begin           
    INSERT INTO TableCollisionBegin 
        SELECT * FROM TableCollisionBegin 
        WHERE [UniqueColID] = @UniqueColID;

    INSERT INTO TableCollisionDetails 
        SELECT * FROM TableCollisionDetails 
        WHERE [UniqueColID] = @UniqueColID;

    INSERT INTO TableCollisionLocation 
        SELECT * FROM TableCollisionLocation 
        WHERE [UniqueColID] = @UniqueColID;

    INSERT INTO TableDriver 
        SELECT * FROM TableDriver 
        WHERE [UniqueColID] = @UniqueColID;

    INSERT INTO TableFollowUp 
        SELECT * FROM TableFollowUp 
        WHERE [UniqueColID] = @UniqueColID;

    INSERT INTO TableOfficerLogs 
        SELECT * FROM TableOfficerLogs 
        WHERE [UniqueColID] = @UniqueColID;

    INSERT INTO TablePolice 
        SELECT * FROM TablePolice 
        WHERE [UniqueColID] = @UniqueColID;

    INSERT INTO TableRecVerified 
        SELECT * FROM TableRecVerified 
        WHERE [UniqueColID] = @UniqueColID;

    INSERT INTO TableSignature 
        SELECT * FROM TableSignature 
        WHERE [IndividualID] = @IndividualID;

    INSERT INTO TableTrailer 
        SELECT * FROM TableTrailer 
        WHERE [UniqueColID] = @UniqueColID;

    INSERT INTO TableValidateLog 
        SELECT * FROM TableValidateLog 
        WHERE [UniqueColID] = @UniqueColID;

    INSERT INTO TableVehicle 
        SELECT * FROM TableVehicle 
        WHERE [UniqueColID] = @UniqueColID;

    INSERT INTO TableWitness 
        SELECT * FROM TableWitness 
        WHERE [UniqueColID] = @UniqueColID;

    INSERT INTO TableInvolvedPerson 
        SELECT * FROM TableInvolvedPerson 
        WHERE [IndividualID] = @IndividualID;

    INSERT INTO TableStatement 
        SELECT * FROM TableStatement 
        WHERE [UniqueColID] = @UniqueColID; 

    INSERT INTO TableCollisionDiagram 
        SELECT * FROM TableCollisionDiagram 
        WHERE [UniqueColID] = @UniqueColID;
END
```

The error that I get is:

> Line 21 Invalid column name 'IndividualID'.

If I remove the line of code inserting `individualID` then it gives the same error about the `UniqueColID`

This is strange because in that given table there IS a column `IndividualID` so I don't know why it won't recognize it....I typed this code in MS Excel then copy pasted it into notepad, could that be why the code isn't working?

I copied one row from that table and as you can see it DOES have `IndividualID`:

```
IndividualID
059D1263-F0F3-4D19-8C56-0FC7D2B5266E
```

Comment: Which line is the 21st? I would suggest marking it in some way.

Comment: I would double check the spelling of the column name in the table.  There might be a letter reversal or something that the eye doesn't easily catch.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM TableSignature WHERE [IndividualID]=" is the line it means. I dont know why but although the microsoft SQL server management studio says line 21 it really means line # + 2 = line 23

so it means line 23 in this case which I stated above

Comment: Can you post structure of TableInvolvedPerson, TableStatement, and TableCollisionDiagram? Look like TableInvolvedPerson table didn't have IndividualID. With that TableStatement or TableCollisionDiagram didn't have UniqueColID.

Comment: BTW, not best practice to insert records from other table. You should explicitly define column names in your inserts.

Comment: I am trying to replicate records in different tables with the same UniqueColID so this is my only option

Comment: @Nadal There's no best practice regarding inserting from another table but you should specify the column names in the insert and don't use `*` in your select e.g. `INSERT INTO TABLE (ColA, ColB,..) SELECT fieldA, FieldB from ` .

Comment: You are commiting so many SQl antipatterns it's hard to know where to start. First, do not insert to more than one table without a try catch block and an explicit transaction or you willl have data integrity issues. Inserts should not be written without specifying both the columns in the insert table and the columns in the select. This is bound to create issues in the future. ANd select * even in selct queries is ahorrible SQL antipattern. Third, why are you inserting duplicate records, this seems counterproductive.

Comment: Comment continued:  And since you are using all the same data from the orginal record likely when you get it to pass the syntax check, you will (I hope) violate the PK and the insert won't work anyway. If you have no PK, then shame on you. Why are you creating queries in Excel for a stored proc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check your table `TableInvolvedPerson` and make sure the column `IndividualID` is spelled the same.

**Updated**

When you updated your question, you added a value for `IndividualID`.  The value you added is a Guid, which can possibly be stored in SQL Server as a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` column. But the type you declared on your stored procedure is a `VARCHAR`.  Can you double check your types? What is the type for IndividualID on both the original table and the table you are copying into? Do they match?

Comment: I tried that already, didnt seem to be the problem....Could it be that I should manually type the code into notepad and not copy paste it from excel into notepad?

Comment: I wouldn't think that should matter. Try backspacing out the IndividualID text and retyping it. That way if any odd characters were included that rendered the same characters as ASCII/UTF-8 but are in fact different, you'll catch them.

Comment: Try running that SELECT statement without the INSERT part. Run it as its own statement, replacing the @IndividualID with a valid ID. Does that SELECT statement work on its own?

Comment: Thank you!!!! what I was doing wrong was that the WHERE statement was incorrect because FROM tablename that I had was incorrect...I put FROM [DBNAME].[dbo].[TableName] and that made the WHERE statement on its own work. HOWEVER, the individualID still seems to be the problem

Comment: it was a very very veryyyyyy stupid mistake....I was suppose to reference the FULL path to the table name anytime I wanted to refer to that table....so this means if I want to access tableCollisionBegin I have to type [DBNAME].[dbo].[tableCollisionBegin]

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using single quotes around the parameters? Both those parameters are varchar and you don't need to do that.

Comment: I noticed that right after I posted question so I did remove it in my code but it didnt change anything

Answer (score 1):

Double check you don't have an oddball Unicode character somewhere that *looks* like what you're expecting but isn't.

I'd also add error checking after each statement so you can get a sensible error message if one of them fails; you can then also rollback a transaction if this needs to be an all-or-nothing update.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that a query like this

```
INSERT INTO `a` SELECT * FROM `a` WHERE `c`=null
```

Won't insert you anything no matter what the values are. If the data in `c` is null, you must use `IS NULL` and **never** `=null`.